# SQL Server Alert Based On Severity Level Not Working

Tags: sql-server, alerts, alert

I am new to SQL Server alerts, and I am trying to setup an alert based on the severity level, that should run a job and send notifications.
In order to test if the alert works correctly I have downloaded a sample corrupted database from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/04/17/example-corrupt-database-to-play-with.aspx, and I have restored the database and issued a query against the database which failed with error 824 and level 24.
But although the error is a severe error and was logged to both the SQL log and the Windows Application Log nothing seemed to work, I have even tested with both an alert an on the specific database and on all databases.
(I have even setup alerts on all other levels from 19 and above just to confirm that nothing is happening.)
However an alert based on error number 824 did work, as well as an alert based on the performance counter's Sql Error counter did worked correctly.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8928/sql-server-alert-based-on-severity-level-not-working in that a restart of the agent solved the problem